# Recieve, change and return data from a Django model on a website

Tags: python, django

**What i have:**

In my Django configuration, I create a `painting` model in `models.py`

```
class Painting(models.Model):
    Number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

When the right URL is called, `views.py` returns a HTML paged rendered with a SQL query.

```
def index(request):
    painting_list = Painting.objects.order_by('id')[:5]
    context_dict = {'paintings':painting_list}

    return render(request, 'binaryQuestionApp/index.html', context=context_dict)
```

Now, I can access the `Number` fields in my HTML like so:

```
<div>
    {% if paintings %}
        <ul>
            {% for painting in paintings %}
            <li> {{ painting.Number }} </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**What i want:**

Next, I wish to be able to change the values on the website. Something like this

```
{{ painting.Number = 1}}  // set the value to 1
{{ painting.Number += 1}} //  or maybe take the current value and increment
```

Next, I would want to send the newly set values back to Django to update the `Painings`, probably with a POST request.

**Question**:

What is the best way to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Note that the Django template language (the `{{ painting.Number }}` stuff) runs _on the server_, before the resulting page is sent to the browser. You shouldn't expect to use similar notation to do things in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a post request either with a form, which is probably the easiest, or javascript. Send the **value** that you want to change the Number field by and the **pk** of the model or something else which you can use to identify the model.

Then in that index view you can handle the post request.

```
def index(request):
    painting_list = Painting.objects.order_by('id')[:5]
    context_dict = {'paintings':painting_list}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # You can add some validation here to check that the values aren't empty
        pk = request.POST['pk'] # if this is what you posted
        value = request.POST['value'] # value to change the number field by
        painting = Painting.objects.get(pk=pk)
        painting.Number += value

    return render(request, 'binaryQuestionApp/index.html', context=context_dict)
```

You can also achieve this with a model form, but this method is probably the easiest one to go for right now.

P.S. I would suggest you make the number field an IntegerField instead of CharField if you want to change the value like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a new Post View with 2 fields, one for the painting id to modify and one for the new value.